# Sqlite and storeDateTimeAsTicks (need convert)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, datetime, xamarin

I used SQLite.Net.Async-PCL in my Xamarin app. Option storeDateTimeAsTicks  was - false. I changed package to SQLite.Net-PCL (becose I need support Android 7.)
I use this code:

```
 var _db= new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
```

Option storeDateTimeAsTicks is true by defult. Now, I do not see the old values in the fields DateTime.

Can I convert these values(olds) to the new format? Is this possible?

Comment: open the database using `SQLiteAsyncConnection(path, false)`, add another column to the table and convert your strings to ticks...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question. I selected  data from table with sql question and convert string to datetime, after  I update data in my table with new value.